# Block pl/sql whit HR db

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

a Create a PL / SQL block that shows ids not assigned to employees.

b. Create a PL / SQL block where you place the department's id and return the name of the head of that department.

c. Create a PL / SQL block where you place the id of the employee and return the names of the charges it has occupied in the past.

the ponit A ITS DONE ---- all the id's are full so it does not show results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBt18.png)

the point B dont work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA5AE.png)

Comment: PL/SQL is oracle only so is there any reason this is tagged with mysql and sqlserver?AND you should show what you have done so far and any difficulties you are having

Comment: my code in point A dont work. i am a noob in plsql i dont understend ! this is my partial final

Comment: 2 possibilities 1) Your logic is wrong - I suggest you use the debugger and step through the code 2) You haven't enable dbms.ouput - try adding a dbms output statement prior to the loop. AND pleas add your code as text so that I can debug it.

Comment: its work, i delete if and worked, perfect

Comment: @ventor Looks the `dbms_output` is not enabled in your session. Click on the `plus` sign at the end and choose the schema.

Comment: As a new contributor to the site welcome. We're here to help but you are responsible for providide the information that allows that to do that. Please read the [ask] section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:
Looks the `dbms_output` is not enabled in your session. Click on the `plus` sign at the end and choose the schema and then re-run the block. See below circled in red.

[image]

Comment: I just saw the employee table and saw that all the IDs are assigned so I could not see an answer in the DBMS.
i have connect the dbms whit the db hr